# Serious memory leaks in web browser using OpenERP

Tags: odoo

My Question is: Is anyone else having bad memory leaks with OpenERP when using MS Internet Explorer? If so, what have you done about it?

Background:

I can see the memory grow by ~5--10 MB every time I load a page. Within a few hours IE gets up to ~1 GB. It's bad enough to require a browser re-start every hour or two. It looks like the browser just creates new fields, widgets, etc... every time a page is loaded, and never gets rid of them or re-uses them.

It's the same when I'm running the server on my personal computer, a local server, or using the OpenERP demo from http://demo.openerp.com/web/webclient/home.

Also, memory use is bad with other browsers (FF & Chrome), too, but IE is the worst. It happens whether I log in as admin, or a regular user. Logging out clears some memory, but not much.

Comment: What browser and web client versions are you using?

Comment: IE 8, Chrome 23.0, Firefox 16.0.2, and whatever web client comes bundled with OpenERP 6.1 all-in-one. Also, the OpenERP server is run on my Windows box, and a Redhat enterprise Linux box, with the same memory problems on the browser.

Comment: Just a note: Firefox does the best -- it starts out around 125MB, and climbs a bit higher during use, but will settle back to close to 125MB. So, it seems to be freeing memory. IE and Chrome are still a problem. Especially IE, because all the users of the app will be on IE, so this is potentially a deal-breaker for OpenERP and me.

Comment: This is with OpenERP 6.1. With a single user (me) clicking away at various screens, adding BoMs and products, I get up to about 1GB memory use in IE8. This is not with heavy use, but not light use, either.

Answer (score 1):

I spent some time testing this, but I wasn't able to repeat what you're experiencing. I used Windows XP and tried Firefox 17, Chrome 19, and IE8.

Both Firefox and Chrome went up ~250 Mb on stress, but when idle eventually settled back to 130 - 150 Mb. IE8 also, but the memory footprint is higher (never below  ~190 Mb).

My personal experience with IE8 and OpenERP web client is not the best: I find it slower, uglier (no rounded corners on buttons) and some things don't work (such as the Search's advanced filters).

I think your first choice migh be trying with later versions of IE: IE9 or even IE10.

Another option might be using OpenERP as a [Chrome App](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95710): your users would open OpenERP web client by clicking on a desktop shortcut, and it's opened in dedicated a window that doesn't look like a browser, but it's actually running Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for checking. Were you using OpenERP 6.1? I'm in a corporate environment, so I'm stuck with IE8, at least for now. It might be possible to get Chrome installed for the users, though.

Comment: Actually, I don't think Chrome will work for me -- some of the widgets don't work correctly. I still get errors with the widgets under IE8, but I can get them to work for a while, at least.

Comment: I'm also using the Windows Task Manager -> Proceses to verify the memory use. I can see it grow each time I load a page. I can fish around and get the ids for various form widgets, and I can see the ids are being incremented with each page load. For example, a text field might have id="widget-197", then id="widget-372", then id="widget-517". In Chrome the widgets sometimes get re-used. In IE8 it looks like they get newly created each time.

Comment: It looks like the best answer is to just refresh a page (either with the button, or shift-refresh). It returns IE8 back to it's starting memory of ~100MB.

Comment: Sorry -- I spoke too soon. IE8 will drop some memory (almost to it's starting amount) if you refresh a page towards the *start* of a session. After you've been going for a while it will drop a little memory on a reload, but it still keeps a fairly huge amount. My guess is that there are several different kinds of memory leaks going on, and one kind (maybe the worst) lets memory get freed up on reload, but the memory from the other kind is used up until a browser restart.

Comment: On further investigation, there is one thing that will free up memory in IE8 without re-starting it. Open the app in a *new* tab and close the *old* tab. Closing the old tab will free up the memory. It's not great, but better than a re-start. I'm guessing that there are some JavaScript <--> DOM circular references that don't get cleared until the whole DOM tree is deleted.